# Problem with optional non-capturing group in Regex

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am trying to do regex parsing and matching and optionally discard the rest of the string.

My strings are of type:

[GROUP 1][delimiter 1][GROUP 2][delimiter 2][GROUP 3][delimiter 3 - optional][REST OF THE STRING - optional]

For example:

```
07. Neospace - Into The Night (Chris Van Buren)
13. Atomic Space Orchestra - Starfleet
```

I am trying to capture GROUP 1, GROUP 2 and GROUP 3 while ignoring REST OF THE STRING

The following regex works well if [delimiter 3] is present:

`(\d+)\. (.*) - (.*)(?: \()`

I am getting "`07`", "`Neospace`" and "`Into The Night`".
But for the second string, there is no match, because my last non-capturing group is mandatory.
When I'm trying to make last group optional like this:

`(\d+)\. (.*) - (.*)(?: \()?` non-capturing group stops working and I am getting "`Into The Night (Chris Van Buren)`" for the GROUP 3 - which is NOT what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the 3rd group has `(` as a delimiter, you can use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) to exclude matching a `(` char.

Note that using `*` as a quantifier can also match an empty string between the delimiters.

If the match should be at the start of the string, you can prepend the pattern with `^`

```
(\d+)\. (.*?) - ([^(\n]*)
```

**Explanation**

- `(\d+)` Capture *group 1*, match 1+ digits
- `\.`  Match `.`
- `(.*?)` Capture *group 2*, match 0+ times any character, as few as possible
- `-` Match literally
- `([^(\n]*)` Capture *group 3*, match 0+ times any character except `(` or a newline

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WTeTet/1).

Comment: Thank you, this works as I need it - the only thing is that trailing spaces from group 3 are captured as well.

Comment: @Alexander Like this?  See https://regex101.com/r/t0gNON/1

Comment: @Alexander If the answer solved the problem, feel free to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Thank you, it does solve the problem (however the question about non-capturing group is still open).